# Extract only the first set of digits from Redshift/PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have below string in my RedShift column = col_name:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet-80 consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor,, 80  Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.

I just need the 1st digits extracted as new column. I tried

```
regexp_replace(item_name,'[^[:digit:]]') as new_col
```

but I get `8080`.

How do I get just `80`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `regexp_substr` is supported:

```
select regexp_substr(col,'\\d+') from t;
```

If not, try this:

```
select regexp_replace(col,'^\\D*(\\d+).*$', '\1') from t
```

Comment: regexp_substr is supported, but neither worked.  For regexp_substr(col,'\d+') I get  "d" as the result. for  regexp_replace(col,'^\D*(\d+).*$', '\1') I get the entire string. Thanks!

Comment: @Hema Can you try now? I think [Redshift requires two slashes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html)

Comment: This worked regexp_substr(item_name,'\\d+'). Thank you Sir!